# Responsive adsense ad unit go over its div

Tags: html, css

According to Google, responsive ads fill the available space dynamically according to the width and height of that provided space:

> "We calculate the required size dynamically based on the width of the ad unit’s parent container, then determine what's the best standard height to go with that width."

I placed a responsive Adsense unit in a div that has a width value of 774px. Here is the div css code:

```
.content-left{
display:table-cell;
width:774px;
max-width:774px;
vertical-align:top;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
height:500px;}
```

The problem is that the adsense unit go over that div and cover the content of the div on the right like shown in the following image.

[image: adsense]

The adsense unit is actually taking about 1100px in width. I use responsive adsense so that ads can resize according to the screen size. If a user browse my site on their smartphone, obviously the ad's size changes accordingly.

In my attempt to solve the problem, I added a new div inside the left div and put the adsense code in it and set the maximum width as follows:

```
.adsenseOnLeft{
max-width:774px;
```

}

That did not solve the issue and adsense unit is still taking more space than its parent div. So how can I make its width not go over the width of the div it is placed inside?

**Update:** The issue is happening only in chrome browser. When I refresh the page, the unit respect it's parent div and doesn't go over it. It only does that when I first browse to any page. 
I checked it in Internet Explorer, the unit stays inside it's container and working as it suppose it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a float and a width?

```
.adsenseOnLeft
{
  float: left;
  width:100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `.adsenseOnLeft` `width` to `100%` it l'll fill your ad respect to your parent div.

```
.adsenseOnLeft
{
width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and still not solved. I cleaned my browser cookies and cache to make sure it loads the fresh code. Still no luck.