# Which is first in CSS: flex-direction row or width 100%?

Tags: css, flexbox

I use a main container with `display:flex`, and `flex-direction:row`. Also I use some child elements with `width:100%`.

The page seems to be fine in all tested browsers except Google pagespeed insights, and also AdSense responsive ads makes the container wider than it have to be.

I am not sure if these are connected, but I'm not sure if flex layout is rendered before I set some child element's width to 100%.

Does anyone know the order of these two CSS properties?

I've created a sample, and it seems I already have issues with it

```css
body {
    max-width: 1150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header, .footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px dotted #b76507;
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}

.boxcontainer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    /*width: 100vw;*/
}

.article {
  max-width: 832px;
  width: 832px;
}

.subcontent1 {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 1100px; /* external content */
}

.extra {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 1px dotted #b76507;
    max-width: 318px;
    width: 318px;
    display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px) {
.extra {
    display: initial;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header class="header">
header
</header>
<main class="boxcontainer">
  <article class="content">
    article
    <div class="subcontent1">
    sub sub sub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub sub sub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub subsub sub
    </div>
  </article>
  <aside class="extra">
    sidebarsidebar
  </aside>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
  footer
</footer>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyBNoX

Updated the sample code to show the problem exactly. The sidebar is pushed outside of the main box just because there is a wide content - even if it has max-width set.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across your question and i'd be happy to try an answer it for you.
Typically flex will come before width, on the element in which you would like to set to 100%, when you're using flex use 100vh instead.
An example of this is:

```
header {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

height: 100vh;
}
```

I know this works as I have taken it straight from a stylesheet for one of my sites.

What you can do to try and reinforce it a bit is this:

```
header {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

height: 100vh;

-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Let me know if this answers your question,

James.

Comment: Thank you for the really detailed answer, but I have issues with width, and this solution seems to address height. Or are these connected somehow in flex?

Comment: just change height to width, should work the exact same.
Let me know if that works for you.
If it doesn't, i'll ask one of my colleagues to see if they know.

Comment: Done, I've tried it using 100vw: it seem to be rendering faster, still https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ - shows my sidebar offscreen.

Comment: I've created a sample which seems to already have some problems. It might be easier to debug this way.

Comment: Have you tried moving `<aside class="extra">
    sidebarsidebar
  </aside>` to before `<div class="subcontent1">` instead of after it? Once you've done this add `float: right;` to the .extra rule in the CSS

Comment: You can also have a look at [this](http://codepen.io/JamesTimms/pen/grygKa). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as the sidebar should be 318px wide, and the whole article should be inside the main body.

Comment: I'll have a play around with it in Atom and see if I can get that working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the solution for you. Second time lucky as they say.

After playing around with the html and the css that you provided via codepen, I have found a way to have the sidebar within the main container, and to the side of the articles.

Your original HTML was correct, the issue was within the CSS.

Your original CSS was

```
body {
max-width: 1150px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.header, .footer {
background-color: #eee;
border: 1px dotted #b76507;
padding: 10px 20px 0;
text-align: center;
}

*, :after, :before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,    main, menu, nav, section, summary {
display: block;
}

.boxcontainer {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
/*width: 100vw;*/
}

.article {
max-width: 832px;
width: 832px;
}

.subcontent1 {
background-color: #eee;
width: 1100px; /* external content */
}

.extra {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left: 1px dotted #b76507;
max-width: 318px;
width: 318px;
display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px) {
.extra {
display: initial;
}
```

I managed to get the sidebar working within the content box, and also wrapping around the article without any bugs with the code

```
body {
max-width: 1150px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px;
display: inline-block;
float: inherit;
}

.header, .footer {
background-color: #eee;
border: 1px dotted #b76507;
padding: 10px 20px 0;
text-align: center;
}

*, :after, :before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,    main, menu, nav, section, summary {
display: block;
}

.boxcontainer {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;

/*width: 100vw;*/
}

.article {
max-width: 832px;
width: 832px;
}

.subcontent1 {
background-color: #eee;
width: 100vw; /* external content */
float: left;
word-break:break-all;
}

.extra {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left: 1px dotted #b76507;
max-width: 318px;
width: 318px;
display: none;
float: right;
word-break:break-all;
}

@media all and (min-width: 850px) {
.extra {
display: initial;
}
```

There are slight changes, all of them quite small.

Comment: Thank you really much for the code and your work, I've tried it in in Codepen, but it seems that it is not right: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWZebq - did I missed something?

Also I have found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518577/responsive-adsense-ad-unit-go-over-its-div - the issue is similar but I'm using flex also there is a "solution" for this here: http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-adsense-responsive-design/25252/ - but I can't believe this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Is that not how you wanted it? Could you explain, in detail, how you would want it? I went by how you described.

Comment: The sidebar should be fixed size: 318px, the article (the remaining part) should be fully responsive, and the whole body's max-width is 1150px. And I'm looking for a solution that a fixed width external content (which is in this case 1100px wide, it could be a picture) wouldn't destroy the whole page layout.

Comment: http://codepen.io/JamesTimms/pen/grygKa
This is the best i've managed to produce at the moment.

Comment: I'm sorry but that shrinks the sidebar to the right which should have a fixed width and the header and footer isn't full width.